# How to search through an array of struct C programming

Tags: c, structure

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN_LINE 80
#define LEN_NAME 30
#define MAX_LINES 30
#define LEN_POS 5
#define LEN_HAND 5
#define LEN_THROW 5
#define LEN_STATUS 20
#define LEN_MLBSTATUS 5

typedef struct
{
    int jerseyNumber;
    char firstName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char lastName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char position[LEN_POS + 1];
    char battingHand[LEN_HAND + 1];
    char throwingHand[LEN_THROW + 1];
    int birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay, heightFeet, heightInches, weight;
    char status[LEN_STATUS + 1];
    char mlbStatus[LEN_MLBSTATUS + 1];


}player_t;

//protype
void displayPlayer(player_t *aPlayerPtr);


int main(void)
{
    FILE * filePtr;
    int index, count;
    char line[LEN_LINE + 1];
    player_t players[MAX_LINES];
    filePtr = fopen("Shrimp.txt","r");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0, count;
        while(index < MAX_LINES && fgets(line, LEN_LINE, filePtr))
        {
            if(14 == sscanf(line, "%i %s %s %s %s %s %i %i %i %i %i %i %s %s",
                           &players[index].jerseyNumber, players[index].lastName,
                           players[index].firstName, players[index].position,
                           players[index].battingHand, players[index].throwingHand,
                           &players[index].birthYear, &players[index].birthMonth,
                           &players[index].birthDay, &players[index].heightFeet,
                           &players[index].heightInches, &players[index].weight,
                           players[index].status, players[index].mlbStatus)

               )
            {
                index++;
            }
        }
    fclose(filePtr);
    count = index;

    for(index = 0; index < count; index = index + 1)
    {
        displayPlayer(&players[index]);
    }


    }
    return 0;
}

void displayPlayer(player_t *aPlayerPtr)
{
    printf("Player %i and his name is %s , %s. His weight is %i and position %s. His Status is %s and his mlb status %s \n",
           aPlayerPtr->jerseyNumber, aPlayerPtr->lastName, aPlayerPtr->firstName,
           aPlayerPtr->weight, aPlayerPtr->position, aPlayerPtr->status, aPlayerPtr->mlbStatus
           );
}
```

Okay so I designed a program to read off information from a file into an array of structs.I am suppose to be able to let the user search players info either using name or jersey number.I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: Huh? Loop and compare? Where's the problem?

Comment: What do you mean be `index = 0, count;` in your code?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. What part of the problem are you stuck on? Sounds like you need to start by prompting the user to enter a name or jersey number to compare with, right? Then as Felix says, do a loop and compare.

Comment: I did use for loop with if statement that is the first thing I tried to do.IF statement used to try and compare userInput to all the elements of jerseyNumber array.I couldn't get it to work then thought need to show all information of the player. By just comparing the jerseyArray to userInput how will that allow me to show all info for that player. I just started using array struct so having hard time and can't find something that will help me accomplish this specific task.

Comment: Probably a good idea to emit a diagnostic if `sscanf` doesn't return the expected number of fields. Otherwise you will be scratching your head due to some unexpected result actually caused by bad data.

Comment: When using `sscanf` on a line of input, it's a good idea to scan one extra dummy field. Then if you get a return value > 14, it indicates there are superfluous elements in the line: that can be diagnosed also. Too many is as bad as not enough.

Comment: The `%s` scanf conversion specifier places no limit on the length of the data; it is very much like the deprecated `gets` function.  Use `"%*s", ..., (int) sizeof array - 1, array)`

Comment: I.e "%40s" means read up to 40 characters. We can replace this constant with `*` to indicate "get the limit from an argument of type `int`".

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN_LINE 80
#define LEN_NAME 30
#define MAX_LINES 30
#define LEN_POS 5
#define LEN_HAND 5
#define LEN_THROW 5
#define LEN_STATUS 20
#define LEN_MLBSTATUS 5
#define MAX_PLAYERS 26

typedef struct
{
    int jerseyNumber;
    char firstName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char lastName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char position[LEN_POS + 1];
    char battingHand[LEN_HAND + 1];
    char throwingHand[LEN_THROW + 1];
    int birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay, heightFeet, heightInches, weight;
    char status[LEN_STATUS + 1];
    char mlbStatus[LEN_MLBSTATUS + 1];


}player_t;

//protype
void displayPlayer(player_t *aPlayerPtr);


int main(void)
{
    FILE * filePtr;
    int index, count;
    char line[LEN_LINE + 1];
    player_t players[MAX_LINES];
    filePtr = fopen("Shrimp.txt","r");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0, count;
        while(index < MAX_LINES && fgets(line, LEN_LINE, filePtr))
        {
            if(14 == sscanf(line, "%i %s %s %s %s %s %i %i %i %i %i %i %s %s",
                           &players[index].jerseyNumber, players[index].firstName,
                           players[index].lastName, players[index].position,
                           players[index].battingHand, players[index].throwingHand,
                           &players[index].birthYear, &players[index].birthMonth,
                           &players[index].birthDay, &players[index].heightFeet,
                           &players[index].heightInches, &players[index].weight,
                           players[index].status, players[index].mlbStatus)

               )
            {
                index++;
            }
        }

    fclose(filePtr);
    count = index;

    for(index = 0; index < count; index = index + 1)
    {
        displayPlayer(&players[index]);
    }

    int jerseyNumber;
    int i;


    printf("Enter jersey number for the player: ");
    scanf("%i",&jerseyNumber);

    for(i=0;i<=MAX_PLAYERS;i++){
        if(jerseyNumber == players[i].jerseyNumber){
            printf("The player's name is %s %s\n",players[i].firstName, players[i].lastName);
        }
    }

    }
    return 0;
}

void displayPlayer(player_t *aPlayerPtr)
{
    printf("JERSEY: %i PLAYER NAME: %s %s POSITION: %s BATTING HAND: %s THROWING HAND: %s BIRTHDAY: %i/%i/%i HEIGHT: %i'%i WEIGHT: %i STATUS: %s MLB 40-STATUS: %s\n\n",
           aPlayerPtr->jerseyNumber,aPlayerPtr->firstName,aPlayerPtr->lastName,aPlayerPtr->position,
           aPlayerPtr->battingHand,aPlayerPtr->throwingHand,aPlayerPtr->birthMonth,aPlayerPtr->birthDay,
           aPlayerPtr->birthYear,aPlayerPtr->heightFeet,aPlayerPtr->heightInches,aPlayerPtr->weight,
           aPlayerPtr->status,aPlayerPtr->mlbStatus
           );
}
```

After going back and looking at it I managed to make it work using jersey number.Using this piece of code

```
int jerseyNumber;
int i;


printf("Enter jersey number for the player: ");
scanf("%i",&jerseyNumber);

for(i=0;i<=MAX_PLAYERS;i++){
    if(jerseyNumber == players[i].jerseyNumber){
        printf("The player's name is %s %s\n",players[i].firstName, players[i].lastName);
    }
}
```

Though now I am stuck in trying to figure out how to do it using name or position

Comment: hint, ask the user what they want to lookup. Then call lookupbyxxxx depending  on what they choose. You already have lookupbynumber (its the for loop at the end)

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN_LINE 80
#define LEN_NAME 30
#define MAX_LINES 30
#define LEN_POS 5
#define LEN_HAND 5
#define LEN_THROW 5
#define LEN_STATUS 10
#define LEN_MLBSTATUS 5
#define MAX_PLAYERS 26

typedef struct
{
    int jerseyNumber;
    char firstName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char lastName[LEN_NAME + 1];
    char position[LEN_POS + 1];
    char battingHand[LEN_HAND + 1];
    char throwingHand[LEN_THROW + 1];
    int birthYear, birthMonth, birthDay, heightFeet, heightInches, weight;
    char status[LEN_STATUS + 1];
    char mlbStatus[LEN_MLBSTATUS + 1];


} player_t;

//protypes for all functions
void displayPlayer(player_t *aPlayerPtr);
void displayWelcome(void);
void resultsProvided(void);
void singleDisplay(player_t *aPlayerPtr);

int main(void)
{
    FILE * filePtr;
    int index, count,i;
    char line[LEN_LINE + 1];
    char userChoice;
    char repeat;
    player_t players[MAX_LINES];
    filePtr = fopen("Shrimp.txt","r");
    if (filePtr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to open file.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        index = 0;
        while(index < MAX_LINES && fgets(line, LEN_LINE, filePtr))
        {
            if(14 == sscanf(line, "%i %30s %30s %5s %5s %5s %i %i %i %i %i %i %10s %5s",
                            &players[index].jerseyNumber, players[index].firstName,
                            players[index].lastName, players[index].position,
                            players[index].battingHand, players[index].throwingHand,
                            &players[index].birthYear, &players[index].birthMonth,
                            &players[index].birthDay, &players[index].heightFeet,
                            &players[index].heightInches, &players[index].weight,
                            players[index].status, players[index].mlbStatus)

              )
            {
                index++;
            }
        }

        fclose(filePtr);
        count = index;

        displayWelcome();
        do
        {
            printf("Choose how you would like to search.\nEnter A to display all players information.\
                \nEnter N to search a player based on name.\nEnter J to search a player based on jersey number.\
                \nEnter P to search a player based on position.\nEnter your choice: ");
            scanf("%c",&userChoice);

            if(userChoice == 'A' || userChoice == 'a'){
            for(index = 0; index < count; index = index + 1)
            {
                displayPlayer(&players[index]);
            }
            }

            if(userChoice == 'J' || userChoice == 'j'){
            int jerseyNumber;

            printf("Enter jersey number for the player: ");
            scanf("%i",&jerseyNumber);

            for(i=0; i<=MAX_PLAYERS; i++)
            {
                if(jerseyNumber == players[i].jerseyNumber)
                {
                    singleDisplay(&players[i]);

                }
            }
            }
            if(userChoice == 'N' || userChoice == 'n'){
            char playerName[LEN_NAME + 1];

            printf("Enter name for the player: ");
            scanf("%s",playerName);

            for(i=0; i<=MAX_PLAYERS; i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(playerName, players[i].firstName)== 0)
                {
                    singleDisplay(&players[i]);

                }
            }
            }
            if(userChoice == 'P' || userChoice == 'p'){
            char playerPosition[LEN_NAME + 1];

            printf("Enter position for the player: ");
            scanf("%s",playerPosition);

            for(i=0; i<=MAX_PLAYERS; i++)
            {
                if(strcmp(playerPosition, players[i].position)== 0)
                {
                    singleDisplay(&players[i]);

                }
            }

            }
            printf ("Would you like to search again?\nEnter Y or y for Yes or any other character to exit this program!\n");
            scanf ("\n%c", &repeat);
        }
        while (repeat == 'Y' || repeat == 'y');
    }
    resultsProvided();

    return 0;
}

void displayPlayer(player_t *aPlayerPtr)
{
    printf("JERSEY: %i PLAYER NAME: %s %s POSITION: %s BATTING HAND: %s THROWING HAND: %s BIRTHDAY: %i/%i/%i HEIGHT: %i'%i WEIGHT: %i STATUS: %s MLB 40-STATUS: %s\n\n",
           aPlayerPtr->jerseyNumber,aPlayerPtr->firstName,aPlayerPtr->lastName,aPlayerPtr->position,
           aPlayerPtr->battingHand,aPlayerPtr->throwingHand,aPlayerPtr->birthMonth,aPlayerPtr->birthDay,
           aPlayerPtr->birthYear,aPlayerPtr->heightFeet,aPlayerPtr->heightInches,aPlayerPtr->weight,
           aPlayerPtr->status,aPlayerPtr->mlbStatus
          );
}

void displayWelcome(void)
{
    printf("Welcome to Adrian's Baseball Program!\n");

}

void resultsProvided(void)
{
    printf("\nResults provided by Adrian.\n");
}

void singleDisplay(player_t *aPlayerPtr)
{
     printf("JERSEY: %i\nPLAYER NAME: %s %s\nPOSITION: %s\nBATTING HAND: %s\nTHROWING HAND: %s\
            \nBIRTHDAY: %i/%i/%i\nHEIGHT: %i'%i\nWEIGHT: %i\nSTATUS: %s\nMLB 40-STATUS: %s\n\n",
           aPlayerPtr->jerseyNumber,aPlayerPtr->firstName,aPlayerPtr->lastName,aPlayerPtr->position,
           aPlayerPtr->battingHand,aPlayerPtr->throwingHand,aPlayerPtr->birthMonth,aPlayerPtr->birthDay,
           aPlayerPtr->birthYear,aPlayerPtr->heightFeet,aPlayerPtr->heightInches,aPlayerPtr->weight,
           aPlayerPtr->status,aPlayerPtr->mlbStatus
          );
}
```

I was able to get almost everything working expect for while loop that allows user to search repeatedly.Also I am having trouble getting else statements to work properly.

```
    if(userChoice == 'J' || userChoice == 'j'){
    int jerseyNumber;

    printf("Enter jersey number for the player: ");
    scanf("%i",&jerseyNumber);

    for(i=0; i<=MAX_PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        if(jerseyNumber == players[i].jerseyNumber)
        {
            singleDisplay(&players[i]);

        }else{
            printf("The jersey number entered is not found.");
        }
    }
    }
```

It loops and even if I enter a number in the array it outputs something like this(no.18 is first jersey number in file)

```
 Welcome to Adrian's Baseball Program!
Choose how you would like to search.
Enter A to display all players information.
Enter N to search a player based on name.
Enter J to search a player based on jersey number.
Enter P to search a player based on position.
Enter your choice: J
Enter jersey number for the player: 18
JERSEY: 18
PLAYER NAME: Matt Tomshaw
POSITION: P
BATTING HAND: R
THROWING HAND: L
BIRTHDAY: 12/17/1988
HEIGHT: 6'2
WEIGHT: 200
STATUS: Active
MLB 40-STATUS: No
```

The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.The jersey number entered is not found.Would you like to practice another number?
    Enter Y or y for Yes or any other character to exit this program!